# Sum of array with tuple of axis : what is the program exactly doing?

Tags: python

I don't understand this code :

```
D=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]
print(np.sum(D, axis=(-2,-1)))
```

If would understand the summation of axis=-2 for example, it would mean that we go at the dimension "-2" and we sum all elements in this dimension.

In a general case, with a D dimensional array called `A`, I will have :

```
np.sum(A,axis=d)
```

that will return me a matrix "B" of dimension D-1 such as

B[i1]...[iD-1]=Sum(A[i1]...[id]...[iD])

where the summation is done on id.

But with a tuple of axis I don't get what it means ? I tried on some example but I don't see what is happening.

Could you help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to sum on all the axes specified in the tuple in the order in which they appear:

```
>>> np.sum(D, axis=-2)
array([[ 5,  7,  9],
       [17, 19, 21]])
>>> np.sum(_, axis=-1)
array([21, 57])
```

`(-2, -1)` sums on the second axis from the inner most, then sums on the last axis.

As a second example, take `(-3,-2,-1)`:

```
>>> np.sum(D, axis=(-3,-2,-1))
78
>>> # explicate summation on (-3,-2,-1)
>>> np.sum(D, axis=-3)
array([[ 8, 10, 12],
       [14, 16, 18]])
>>> np.sum(_, axis=-2)
array([22, 26, 30])
>>> np.sum(_, axis=-1)
78
```